# Google App Engine: How to be notified when APIs change or become available?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am thinking about writing a GAE app but am a little hesitant because the EULA gives Google full rights to change their APIs anytime they want, for any reason. Obviously, they'd be out of business quick if they just 'upped and refactored their entire APIs, so I have to imagine they have some kind of notification system, perhaps even an RSS feed, etc. to notify developers well in advance of looming changes, or new features coming out in future releases.

However, for the life of me I can't seem to find any trace of the existence of such a notification system. Perhaps the Google forums is the only place to get such updates?

I guess I'm asking any battle-worn GAE veterans for re-assurance that there are reliable ways of getting notifications about policy or API changes from Google such that I could react and make the necessary app changes without production breaking or impacting any clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be notified when one particular issue or a feature is implemented or something, one good way is to star it in the [issues list](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list). Once you do that you will start getting notifications on status changes or new comments regarding a specific issue.

Now for the big changes you don't have to worry about stuff that they are deprecating, since no matter what it's not happening in a day but in a year.

For new up coming features and when they are becoming available for private/public testing I would suggest you to subscribe to the official [Google App Engine Blog](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com). For every new version they are posting a [detailed description](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/09/app-engine-172-released.html) with links to the change logs.

Comment: Even if they do refractor their API, it shouldn't take you but a few hours, to update your code.  You also don't have to use the current version, until they discontinue the support, for the previous version.  This of course assumes you write your program the correct way.